# Linux workqueue vs bottom-half interrupt

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing a driver for an network interface device. I can receive interrupts from the device (Rx data coming from the line), but the driver can also be requested by the User space to send out some data (Tx). Both Rx and Tx can occur completely asynchronously.

On Rx interrupt, my driver would schedule a worker in the shared workqueue, for later processing. On Tx, the user space would call an IOCTL which would also schedule a worker (different one) in the shared workqueue.
The problem i am facing is that, while i was expecting that the workers would execute in the order they were scheduled, it seems that the worker scheduled *from the interrupt handler* would preempt execution of the worker from User Space.

Is my observation correct ? Can i say that, a bottom-half interrupt would ALWAYS preempt execution of an existing "regular" worker ?
Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: If you want work items to be handled one at a time, you can create your own ordered (single-threaded) workqueue using `alloc_ordered_workqueue` or `create_singlethread_workqueue`.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for that. Does it mean then that what i am observing is indeed correct, means that i cannot rely on ordered execution for the standard shared workqueue ?

Comment: The shared workqueues are multi-threaded and several CPUs could be running work items from the same workqueue. Normally, a work item runs by preference on the CPU that queued it, although it is possible to queue the work item to be run on a specific CPU.

Comment: ok, i got it. Although i have only one core and cpu, there must be several threads there, which actually make sense to handle irq's and ioctl more efficiently. I will use an ordered queue then. Thanks !

Comment: A quick update: using the ordered_workqueue solved my problem, everything is nicely serialised now !